# THtmlViewer for DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

I need a version of PBears thtmlviewer that will work in DelphiXE.

I found the Google code page (http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer) where is is now supported but I cannot figure out where/how to download a version I can use.

I also cannot figure out how to even ask someone on that website.

Am I missing something obvious or is there no download available yet?

Steve...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There don't appear to be any downloads set up, but you can obtain the source with SVN, as described on the Source tab.

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://thtmlviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ thtmlviewer-read-only
```

It's a bit simpler than Google Code describes if you download and install TortoiseSVN.  It adds SVN functionality into Windows Explorer.  Then just go to where you want to download the code to, right-click and select "SVN Checkout...", and enter `http://thtmlviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/` as the `URL of repository`, set a checkout folder, and hit OK, and it'll download the code for you.

Comment: Never tried it, but can't the SVN integration in Delphi XE do that, too?

Comment: @Rudy: Probably, but I've never tried it either so I couldn't explain how.  By the time XE came out I'd already been using TortoiseSVN for years.

Comment: @Rudy: I just did. It works but somehow I got a version that doesn't look up to date at all. At least compared to their latest sources. Packed with error messages too.

Comment: @Domus: did you really get the latest sources? You might have to find another branch.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest downloads at http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/downloads/list now :)